# Test website can't be reached despite setting up DNS in local hosts file and adding a virtual host to Apache config

Tags: domains, htaccess, apache, windows

I am trying to set up a domain on my development machine so that I cant test slightly more complex htaccess rules. I am trying to set up `example.city` domain. Following what I find by googling, I have done the following:

Windows hosts file `Windows/System32/drivers/etc`

```
127.0.0.1   example.city
127.0.0.1   www.example.city
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

And I have flushed the DNS cache more than 20 times by now by using

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

When I ping `example.city`, I get the following, so I am confident that this part is fine.

```
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Next I set up the `httpd-vhosts/conf` file in `xampp/apache/conf/extra`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.city
  DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/city"
  ServerName example.city
  ServerAlias *.example.city
  ErrorLog "logs/example.city-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/example.city-access.log" common
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.city
  DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias *.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I stopped and started apache.

When I type in `localhost/city` in the browser it executes the html there.

I have flushed the browser cache and tried 2 different browsers.  When I type in `example.city` or `http://example.city`, I get the following

> #### This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at `http://example.city/` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> - ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

The two error logs files got created but are blank.

Am I not allowed to do this?  Or have I missed a step?

Comment: If you're using XAMPP then your title is wrong, as it's not a Windows Server. Secondly, that's a configuration issue. Your computer is pinging the right address, but XAMPP isn't configured correctly to handle the URL.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins XAMPP is available for Windows, Linux and macOS.

Comment: @MrWhite, yes, but "Windows Server" typically and specifically refers to IIS.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins  I know its not configured properly.  Hence the post here :-)  And I have apache in the tags.  How about an attempt at telling me what I have done wrong ?

Comment: Is your web server listening on 127.0.0.1?   What do the Apache logs show?

Comment: "The two error logs files got created but are blank." - The error logs are created when the server is started. This has nothing to do with the request (which doesn't appear to be reaching your server), but at least means your conf files are being read - a good sign. I would try this with a completely different/random domain name, one that you have not been using at all (from your previous questions, I'm guessing that `example.city` is an actual domain you have been using?). For `localhost/city` to work, you must have some other config defined elsewhere?

Comment: Check the network traffic in the browser when making this request to get more detail... what IP is the browser trying to connect to?

Comment: _Aside:_ Your `<VirtualHost>` doesn't appear to be set up quite right (although not the cause of your immediate problem). I would think `DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"` should be `DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/city"`, to avoid having to specify the `/city` subdirectory. And you should never be overriding `<Directory />` here. This should reference the document root. eg. `<Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/city">`.

Comment: Don't use arbitrary domain names or TLDs. Either use TLDs specifically set aside as private, such as `.example`. Or register once for all a real domain name, in any TLD (do note however some of them like `.dev` do have requirements about certificates for HTTP, etc.) and then use it as suffix for any of your local needs.

Comment: @MrWhite  That was a transcription error, I have corrected it.  After Stephens' reply, I have Firefox working, so I guess my change were okay.  Interestingly I just realised that 127.0.0.1 no longer works.  But localhost does.  With regards to previous comment, No, I am not using a real domain example.city.  I am using a .city domain in real life, so decided to use example.city for testing

Comment: @RohitGupta "No, I am not using a real domain example.city. I am using a .city domain in real life, so decided to use example.city for testing" Except that IETF did not set up `example` in all TLDs to be used as example, only officially `example.com`,  `example.net` and the whole `.example` TLD. Anything else could be considered a real domain and is not specifically set aside for documentation. As `city` TLD has nothing specific (not being in HSTS preload list like `dev`, `app`, `new` or `day`), you can use directly  `.example` TLD in your examples.

Comment: @RohitGupta "I just realised that 127.0.0.1 no longer works. But localhost does." - What do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly? The IP address will likely be resolving to the _default_ (ie. first) vHost. In your example above you have explicitly defined a vHost for `localhost`, but not the IP address.

Comment: @MrWhite chrome says "this site cant be reached"  localhost shows me the xampp dashboard.  ping works fine on both addresses.  On firefox, both now go to example.city.   Which indicates DOH issues as in the answer below.  I will reset and start again with a different domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser that you are using to test likely has DNS over HTTPS (DoH) enabled.  That is a feature where the browser ignores the local DNS settings and instead looks up DNS from its own internet provider. This causes your browser to ignore any DNS overrides made through your local `hosts` file. The solution is going to be to disable this browser feature in all the browsers with which you are testing.

#### Chrome

Open `chrome://settings/security` and turn off "Use secure DNS."

After changing this setting you may also have to clear your cache from `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` by choosing to "Clear browsing data" for "All time" and choosing "Cached images and Files"

#### Firefox

Go into the menu then "settings" then "general", and scroll to "Network Settings" and click "Settings..."  Scroll down to "Enable DNS over HTTPS" and uncheck the box. ([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https#w_opt-out))

Comment: Firefox now works.  But curiously on both Chrome and therefore Brave, I cant find "Secure DNS Lookups"  flag.  Search does not find it and I have scrolled through them to look for similar names.  Bummer, because I am using Chrome for debugging, so I can flush the cache constantly without affecting my browsing.  I see on googlesupport that people have been complaining in 2020 that it doesnt exist.  At least it proves that my config is ok.  I might just get a raspberry pi and try and set it up on that.

Comment: I updated the Chrome instructions after testing it myself.  I searched for "DNS" in settings.  It is now called "Use secure DNS"

Comment: Cant "Use Secure DNS" either.  I am normally up with my updates.  My chrome version is 980.4758.82.  I just checked, its the latest.  The only other thing I found when googling, was that its disabled in "Managed Browsers", whatever that means.

Comment: I looked in chrome policies.  and "DnsOverHttpsMode" is not set and its value is null.

Comment: On StackOverflow: [Google Chrome Ignoring Hosts File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636711/google-chrome-ignoring-hosts-file).  One answer suggest clearing the cache, another suggests using `.local` domains for testing for which Chrome evidentially always consults your local hosts file.

Comment: That doesnt work at all.  It just goes to the web for searching.  But I did come across a page where it suddenly told me at the top of browser that my browser was managed by my organisation.  I am the organisation.  So, I suspect a virus scanner or firewall.   But why is firefox not managed then ?  Task for another day :-)